# Azure website can't login to AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, adal

I made a mvc web app based on this example: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/MicrosoftGraph.Office365.Generic/OfficeDevPnP.MSGraphAPIDemo

Strange thing is when I work from localhost then all the auth2 authentication works. When I deploy on Azure this happens:

On first page call on Azure I get the response:

```
An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

On second page call the message:

```
IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: '__AADInstance____AuthenticationContext__/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133617/mvc-to-azure-active-directory-sign-on-replying-with-bad-request-and-message-wi) post on SO, but I've already set the tenant GUID in the configuration and the AAD privileges are "read directory data" and "sign in and read user profile"

Are there any configuration options on Azure maybe in the new management portal that I should grant?

I have a single tenant addin and this keys in web.config:

```
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:AuthenticationContext" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="GUID..." />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44300/" />
    <add key="ida:MicrosoftGraphResourceId" value="https://graph.microsoft.com" />
```

I tried the section authorization/authentication  in the new management portal to enable app service authentication with aad
and could enter the first site of the addin, but the authorization code from my addin was not called and specific file functions don't work if you rely on the portal authorization.

Comment: Have you entered all of the required keys in 'appSettings' section of `web.config`?

Comment: I've updated the post with current appSettings, Also double checked the sign on  url:  h t t p s://xxx.azurewebsites.net  and reply urls   h t t p s://xxx.azurewebsites.net , h t t p://xxx.azurewebsites.net with and without ending slash, still the same.